# ssh login in ec2 to change file permission

Tags: amazon-ec2

I need to login in the ec2 aws server to change the file permission. I've .pem and .ppk file on my server and gitbash installed.
Please guide me how can I login to the server and change the file permission.

Answer (score 1):

Here the official documentation from Amazon with SSH/Putty tutorials to connect to your instance: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstances.html

(But assuming you are using Unix/Linux OS)

You could log in to the ec2 instance with the command:

**ssh -i /route/to/your/file.pem user@serverUrl.com** 
(if you have public Url or in your /etc/hosts file or with your IP)

Then, you are logged in the EC2, you could `cd` to the desired folder and change the permisions with a `chmod`.

In the /etc/hosts file, you could change the IP of your instance for the `serverUrl.com` like:

`XX.XX.XX.XX serverUrl.com`

Hope this helps!